# Quarto - How to adjust Custom Layout for Title Blocks and Table of Contents?

Tags: quarto

I am currently working on a quarto html-document(article layout) and want to `page-left` or `screen-inset` align the layout depending on content.
This works for markdown divs, code cell output and even the reference list via the `#refs` id. But I am unable to apply custom layouts to the `title-block` and and the `table of contents`(and therefore align them with the rest of the document). Due to this two questions arise:

1. How can I access `title-block` and the `table of contents` in order to apply a custom layout?
2. Is there a way to apply `page-left`(or any other format option for that matter) to the whole document and then adjust individual cells when overflow is needed?

Here is a simple dummy .qmd file which should illustrate my issue(`jupyter`,`pandas` and `IPython` libraries required to run):

````
---
title: 'Quarto Test Document'
title-block-banner: false
description: 'A Quarto Document for Test Purposes'
abstract: 'This title block is `body` aligned' 
date: today
date-format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
toc: true
toc-title: Table of Contents (`body` aligned)
toc-expand: true
toc-location: body
number-sections: true
format: 
    html:
        theme: default
        title-block-style: default
        embed-resources: true
        page-layout: article
        smooth-scroll: true
execute: 
  echo: false
  enable: true 
jupyter: python3
---

## First Section {.column-page-left}

This section is `page-left` aligned. Its layous differs from the title block.

```{python}
#| label: tbl-test_table
#| tbl-cap: 'This table is `page-left` aligned'
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Markdown

data_dict = {'a': range(0,5), 'b': range(5,10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

Markdown(df.to_markdown())
```
## References (the reference list is `page-left` aligned) {.column-page-left}
::: {#refs .column-page-left}

:::
````

Comment: Can you provide a complete quarto document (not just a fraction)? That would make easier to test things!

Comment: I edited the original question and added a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be adding the class `column-page-left` to the Quarto main content using javascript, which will affect the whole document's main content (except the margin sidebar) and then no need to use `column-page-left` for sections separately.

So add the following html file in your quarto document using `include-in-header`.

**add-class.html**

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    (function() {
      let mainContent = document.querySelector('main#quarto-document-content');
      if (!mainContent.classList.contains('column-page-left')) {
       mainContent.classList.add('column-page-left'); 
      };
    })();
  });
</script>
```

**document.qmd**

````markdown
---
title: 'Quarto Test Document'
title-block-banner: false
description: 'A Quarto Document for Test Purposes'
abstract: 'This title block is `body` aligned' 
date: today
date-format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
toc: true
toc-title: Table of Contents (`body` aligned)
toc-expand: true
toc-location: body
number-sections: true
format: 
    html:
        theme: default
        title-block-style: default
        embed-resources: true
        page-layout: article
        smooth-scroll: true
        include-in-header: add-class.html
execute: 
  echo: false
  enable: true 
jupyter: python3
---


## First Section

This section is `page-left` aligned. Its layous differs from the title block.

```{python}
#| label: tbl-test_table
#| tbl-cap: 'This table is `page-left` aligned'
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Markdown

data_dict = {'a': range(0,5), 'b': range(5,10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

Markdown(df.to_markdown())
```

## References (the reference list is `page-left` aligned)

::: {#refs}

:::
````

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine. Will keep in mind to customize my quarto documents via javascrip, although it would be nice to have more builtin control over styles in quarto.